# Cannot run NetBeans on Ubuntu 14.04 because it doesn't recognize my java path

Tags: ubuntu, netbeans, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to run NetBeans on Ubuntu, and when I go to run the .exe, it does not recognize my java path even though that is the same jdk path I use for other IDEs such as Android Studio.

[image]

after pressing yes...

[image]

usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

[image]

Also, when I try to run netbeans from the terminal, it says it is not installed even though I did install it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be NetBeans in menu and link on desktop to that shell script `netbeans` in bin folder which you can use to run NetBeans. You can also execute it directly via double clicking on it or executing `./netbeans` in terminal if terminal is open in bin folder or executing `~/netbeans-8.0.2/bin/netbeans` if terminal is open elsewhere. Do not know how you managed to execute `exe` on Linux, guess you have `Wine` installed. If `Wine` is trying to run NetBeans that Linux JDK is not available. But you do not want to run NetBeans as Windows program on Linux.
By default NetBeans 8 will install in your home folder own JDK `~/jdk1.8.0_xx` and use that JDK.
Ubuntu knows only about programs installed via `apt`. Since you installed it via usual NetBeans download and not using `apt` Ubuntu does not know it is installed.
BTW that NetBeans install will fail to run if there is no Java installed on host system.

Comment: Yea my problem was that I was trying to run the .exe which would be running as a windows program on linux. I didn't see the new shortcut on the desktop. Clicked that and it works. It also put an icon on the dock.

Answer (score 0):

If you have java installed, check the path for **netbeans_jdkhome** in netbeans.conf. You can find this file at ***netbeans_installation_dir***/netbeans/etc/netbeans.conf.

In netbeans.conf see this

netbeans_jdkhome="path_to_java"

If path_to_java is incorrect, replace it with your actual java path.

**Note** this path is without /bin directory, so don't include /bin at the end of the path.